SSL verification fails for kubelet API
wget https://$NODE_IP:10250/stats/summary --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --ca-certificate=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

ERROR: cannot verify 10.224.0.12's certificate, issued by 'CN=aks-agentpool-38123352-vmss00000K':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
    ERROR: certificate common name 'aks-agentpool-38123352-vmss00000K' doesn't match requested host name '10.224.0.12'.
To connect to 10.224.0.12 insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

SSL verification fails only for kubelet API.
The same certificate is working fine for kubernetes api server.
https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/pods --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --ca-certificate=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

I don't want to skip the SSL verification.

If possible, you should use the node's hostname (which should match the CN of the certificate) instead of the IP address when making the request. This way, the certificate verification process can succeed because the CN will match the hostname.
wget https://aks-agentpool-38123352-vmss00000K:10250/stats/summary --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --ca-certificate=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt


https://www.deepnetwork.com/blog/2020/01/13/kubelet-api.html - Found the exact reason.
There is no self-signed certificates available for kubelet api. thanks

deepnetwork.com/blog/2020/01/13/kubelet-api.html - Found the exact reason. There is no self-signed certificates available for kubelet api. thanks

Instead of just shareing the link, include the text from the link as the links tends to get unservisable over the period of time.
